# I can not upload an image from one of my due dialog pop ups, but I can upload from the other using the same exact function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, file-upload

I can not upload an image from one of my due dialog pop ups, but I can upload from the other using the same exact function. It works in the second dialog(editDialog) but not in the first (intakeDialog). The output of the variables associated the w/ image upload file for the correct one(editDialog) in console is:

```
idf: files_uploader
app.js:238600 file1: [object File]
app.js:238609 num of picture1
app.js:238614 file: [object File]
```

The output of the variables associated w/ the image upload file for the failing one(editDialog) in console is:

```
app.js:238597 idf: files_uploader
app.js:238600 file1: undefined
app.js:238609 num of picture1
```

Any help on this is GREATLY appreciated! My code is below:

```
<!-- Intake Dialog -->
<v-dialog
        v-model="intakeDialog"
        width="700"
>
    <v-card>
        <v-card-title
                class="headline grey lighten-2 p-3"
                primary-title
        >
            <span>{{current_sample.number}}</span>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <span>{{current_sample.sample_accession}}</span>

        </v-card-title>
        <v-container>
            <v-layout wrap class="form-blocks">
                <v-flex>
                    <p><v-flex sm3 v-for="media in current_sample.media"  :key="media.id">
                        <v-btn @click="delete_image(media.id)">[X]</v-btn> <img :src="'https://orderinformation.s3.amazonaws.com/' + media.path" class="rotateImg" />
                    </v-flex> </p>
                </v-flex>


                <v-flex sm10>

                    <label  class="m-l-1 m-r-1"><p style="font-weight: bold">Image Uploader </p></label>
                    <input type="file"
                           name = "file"
                           class="form-control-file border"
                           id="files_uploader"
                           multiple
                           ref="image"
                           accept="image/*"
                           placeholder="Order #"
                           v-on:change="fileValidation(1), previewFile()"/>
                    <img style="height:80px; margin:15px; visibility: hidden;"
                         src=""
                         height="80"
                         alt="Sample preview..."
                         class="PreviewImage"/>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex sm2>
                    <label  class="m-l-1 m-r-1"><p style="font-weight: bold; color:red">Make Image Default?</p></label>
                    <b-form-checkbox
                            id="default_check"
                            v-model="current_sample.status"
                            name="default_check"
                            value="default"
                            unchecked-value="not_default"
                    >
                    </b-form-checkbox>
                </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
        </v-container>
        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn
                    color="red"
                    text
                    @click="intakeDialog = false, current_sample={}"
            >
                Cancel
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn
                    color="green darken-1"
                    @click="upload_image()"
            >
                Submit
            </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
</v-dialog>
<!-- Edit Dialog -->
<v-dialog
        v-model="editDialog"
        width="700"
        class="editDialog"
>
    <v-card>
        <v-card-title
                class="headline grey lighten-2 p-3"
                primary-title
        >
            <span>{{current_sample.number}} / {{current_sample.batch_no}} / {{current_sample.sample_accession}}</span>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <span></span>

        </v-card-title>
        <v-container>
            <v-layout wrap class="form-blocks">
                <label  class="m-l-1 m-r-1"><p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:24px !important; line-height: 32px !important">Sample Verification</p></label>
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr valign="top" colspan="3">
                        <td width="33%">
                            <v-layout wrap class="form-blocks">
                                <label  class="m-l-1 m-r-1">Sample Verified &nbsp;</label>
                                <b-form-checkbox
                                        id="accepted_check"
                                        v-model="current_sample.accepted_for_testing"
                                        name="accepted_check"
                                        value="Yes"
                                        unchecked-value="No"
                                >
                                </b-form-checkbox>
                            </v-layout>
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%">
                            <v-layout wrap class="form-blocks"><label  class="m-l-1 m-r-1">Accession ID fixed? &nbsp;</label>
                                <b-form-checkbox
                                        id="accession_id_check"
                                        v-model="current_sample.accession_id_fixed"
                                        name="accession_id_check"
                                        value="1"
                                        unchecked-value="0"
                                >
                                </b-form-checkbox>
                            </v-layout>
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%">
                            <v-layout wrap class="form-blocks"><label  class="m-l-1 m-r-1">Batch# Validated &nbsp;</label>
                                <b-form-checkbox
                                        id="bash_no_check"
                                        v-model="current_sample.batch_no"
                                        name="bash_no_check"
                                        value="1"
                                        unchecked-value="0"
                                >
                                </b-form-checkbox>
                            </v-layout>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr colspan="3">
                        <td>
                            <v-layout wrap class="form-blocks"><label  class="m-l-1 m-r-1">Sample Rejected &nbsp;</label>
                                <b-form-checkbox
                                        id="rejected_no_check"
                                        v-model="current_sample.sample_rejected"
                                        name="rejected_no_check"
                                        value="Yes"
                                        unchecked-value="No"
                                >
                                    <div class="container" v-if="current_sample.sample_rejected">
                                        <v-text-field
                                                label="Rejection Comments"
                                                v-model="current_sample.rejection_comment"
                                                name="rejection_comment"
                                                class="break">
                                        </v-text-field>
                                    </div>
                                </b-form-checkbox>
                            </v-layout>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <v-flex sm10>
                    <div id="selector" class="flex-row">

                        <div class="container" id="app-container">

                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <v-select
                                                v-model="current_sample.sample_received_date_time_1"
                                                :items="datesList"
                                                label="Select dates"
                                                item-text="date"
                                                id="select_dates"
                                                value="2019-10-01" >
                                        </v-select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <v-select
                                                v-model="current_sample.sample_received_date_time_2"
                                                :items="hourList"
                                                label="Select hour"
                                                item-text="hour"
                                                id="select_hour"
                                                value="2019-10-01"
                                        >
                                        </v-select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <v-select
                                                v-model="current_sample.sample_received_date_time_3"
                                                :items="minuteList"
                                                label="Select minute"
                                                item-text="minute"
                                                id="select_minute"
                                                value="2019-10-01"
                                        >
                                        </v-select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="file"
                           name = "file"
                           class="form-control-file border"
                           id="files_uploader"
                           multiple
                           ref="image"
                           accept="image/*"
                           placeholder="Order #"
                           v-on:change="fileValidation(1), previewFile()"/>
                    <v-flex>
                        <p>
                            <v-flex sm3 v-for="media in current_sample.media"  :key="media.id">
                                <v-btn @click="delete_image(media.id)">[X] </v-btn> <img :src="'https://orderinformation.s3.amazonaws.com/' + media.path" class="rotateImg PreviewImage" />
                            </v-flex>
                        </p>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-flex>

            </v-layout>
        </v-container>
        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn
                    color="red"
                    text
                    @click="editDialog = false, current_sample={}"
            >
                Cancel
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn
                    color="green darken-1"
                    @click="updateOrderInfo(current_sample), upload_image()"
            >
                Submit
            </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
</v-dialog>
<script>
    methods: {
        upload_image(value = 0, accession = '696668')
        {
            let idf = (value = 0) ? 'file_uploader' : 'files_uploader';
            console.log("idf: " + idf);
            this.uploading = true;
            let file = document.getElementById(idf).files[0];
            console.log("file1: " + file);
            let accession_number = `${this.current_sample.sample_accession}`;
            var order_number = `${this.current_sample.number}`;
            var order_details_id = `${this.current_sample.id}`;
            var checkdefault = `${this.current_sample.status}`;
            /*for(i=0; i<current_sample.media.length; i++)
{

}*/

            console.log("num of picture" + Object.keys(this.current_sample.media).length);
            if (Object.keys(this.current_sample.media).length <= 1) {

                if (file) {
// create reader
                    console.log("file: " + file);
                    let reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsText(file);
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
// browser completed reading file - display it
// alert(e.target.result);
                        let formData = new FormData();
                        formData.append("order_number", order_number);
                        formData.append("order_details_id", order_details_id);
                        formData.append("file", file);
                        formData.append("acession_number", accession_number);
                        formData.append("checkdefault", checkdefault);
                        axios
                            .post("/api/order_master/uploadPicture", formData, {
                                headers: {
                                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                                }
                            })
                            .then(response => {
                                this.upload = null;
                                this.imagename = null;
                                this.uploading = false;
                                file = null;
                                this.closeModal();
                                this.snackbar.text = `Sample ${this.current_sample.sample_accession} picture(s) weight has been upload!`;
                                this.snackbar.color = "success";
                                this.snackbar.show = true;
                            }).catch((error) => {
                            console.error(error);
                            this.snackbar.text = "A problem occurred, try again!";
                            this.snackbar.color = "danger";
                            this.snackbar.show = true;
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ,

//1671
        fileValidation: function (value = 0) {
// let idf = ( value = 0 )?'file_uploader': 'files_uploader';

            let fileInput = document.getElementById('files_uploader');

            let filePath = fileInput.value;
            let allowedExtensions = /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.svg|\.gif)$/i;
            if (!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)) {
                alert('Please upload file having extensions .jpeg/.jpg/.png/.gif only.');
                fileInput.value = '';
                return false;
            } else {
//Image preview
                if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]) {
                    let reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        let id = (value = 0) ? 'imagePreview' : 'imagesPreview';
                        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<img src="' + e.target.result + '"/>';
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is this a *minimal* example?

Comment: @LegendofPedro what do you mean by a minimal example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Removing code may highlight where the problem lies.

Comment: @LegendofPedro Ok, yes it is. This a version started from scratch that removes unnecessary code and still has the same issue.  I can not figure out why this upload_image function only works on one pop up dialog